# Can I execute a batch delete with join statements?

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to execute the following bulk delete using jpql:

```
            " DELETE " +
            " FROM AutAnt aa " +
            "   JOIN aa.person p " +
            "   JOIN p.employees e" +  
            " WHERE e = :employess " +
            "   AND (" +
            "       aa.dateFrom BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd" +
            "       OR" +
            "       aa.dateTor BETWEEN :dataStart AND :dateEnd" +
            "   )");
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
unexpected token: JOIN
```

The [JPA docs](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_overview_query.html#ejb3_overview_query_delete) state that "Delete by query uses the same JPQL syntax as normal queries, with one exception: begin your query string with the delete keyword instead of the select keyword"

I have the following select query which works perfectly:

```
            " SELECT aa " +
            " FROM AutAnt aa " +
            "   JOIN aa.person p " +
            "   JOIN p.employees e" +  
            " WHERE e = :employess " +
            "   AND (" +
            "       aa.dateFrom BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd" +
            "       OR" +
            "       aa.dateTor BETWEEN :dataStart AND :dateEnd" +
            "   )");
```

Changing the first statement of the delete query to **"DELETE aa"** raises a different exception.

Is this a Hibernate bug, or am I missing something here.

Cheers!

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by deleting a join?

Comment: I'm trying to delete a record in a table based on a value which is in another table which the first table has a relationship with. For example, I have two tables: 'Book' and 'Author'. The 'Author' table has a 'dateOfBirth' column. I need to delete all books who were written by authors who are older than 30 years old.

Answer (score 4):

Joins are not supported in Hibernate bulk DML operations. From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html#batch-direct):

> No [Section 16.4, “Forms of join syntax”](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins-forms), either implicit or
>   explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be
>   used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain
>   joins.

As suggested in the documentation, you could write semantically the same statement with the help of subqueries:

```
delete AutAnt where id in
  (select aa.id from AutAnt aa join aa.person p ...)
```